# SQL Query with Results with different where clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I tried searching for an answer to this question...I may not be wording my search correctly as I am not a super guru in SQL.

Situation:
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 database, two tables I'm interested in right now, call them OpenOrders and InvoicedOrders.

I want to pull OpenOrders for the month, quarter, and year, and then InvoicedOrders for the month, quarter, and year, grouped by sales zone (sales zone in the same table).

I can't post an image, but if you imagine we have 5 sales zone, and then the 6 date ranges noted above, there would be 7 rows and 5 columns in the query result.  shown in text below if displays correctly.

```
1  10000  40000   12500  53200   12500  61180
2  23000  53000   25500  70490   25500  81063.5
3  45000  75000   47500  99750   47500  114712.5
4  43000  73000   45500  97090   45500  111653.5
5  76000  106000  78500  140980  78500  162127
```

What I want to do is a solution that is ideally one query, or a few queries, not 6 queries.  I will be using this query in an SSRS report and was not successful with nested queries as those queries returned the 'returned more than one result' error.

I am now thinking of using a temp table to select the first row, insert into temp table, select second row, insert into temp table, then select all results from temp table and drop temp table.

Hope I provided enough info!

Is a temp table an ideal solution, or is there a better one out there?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you got a solution for partial problems? For instance, can you pull aggregated data for just one of the tables (either one)? In short, what have you tried and where specifically are you stuck? Please update your question with that info.

Comment: Andriy,Yes I can pull the data for just one of the tables.  Stuck where I want to pull the month data in one column, and the year in another.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get one result set back, consider creating a view  and use UNION to join the results for these different queries inside.  You can then run a select to get results from the view like a table.